# BeautifulSoup - trying to parse website but unsure how to parse json script?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

As a fun side project I have been trying to parse a website for a random fact of the day.
I decided to try my hand at this today with BeautifulSoup4 and urllib3. Sadly however I am unsure how to dive any deeper into a script element than I already have gotten.

This is my current level of output:

```
{
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "Article",
"headline": "Fact of the Day: 51 Facts Of the Day for 3/19/2019 ←FACTSlides→",
"image": "https://www.FACTSlides.com/imgs/ishots/8224.png",
"author": "Luke Reiner",
"genre": "facts",
"publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "FACTSlides",
    "logo": {
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "url": "https:\/\/www.factslides.com\/imgs\/logo.png"
    }
},
"url": "https://www.factslides.com/s-Fact-Of-The-Day",
"mainEntityOfPage": "https://www.factslides.com/s-Fact-Of-The-Day",
"datePublished": "2019-03-19",
"dateCreated": "2019-03-19",
"dateModified": "2019-03-19",
"description": "Description.",
"articleBody": "Article clutter here."
}
```

The facts themselves are stored under the `articleBody` and are not delimited, I was going to use '. ' as the Delimiter if I got that far.

This is the code I have so far:

```
""" Get a random fact. """
import argparse
import json
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

PARAMETERS = {
    "u": ["url", "passes in a url.", "1"],
}

PARSER = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="Arguments to parse a url."
)

HTTP = urllib3.PoolManager()


def __load_args(parser, cfg_list):
    """ Loads the passed arguments. """
    for cfg_key in cfg_list:
        if len(cfg_list[cfg_key]) > 3:
            parser.add_argument(
                "-" + cfg_key,
                "--" + cfg_list[cfg_key][0],
                help=cfg_list[cfg_key][1],
                action=cfg_list[cfg_key][2],
                nargs=cfg_list[cfg_key][3],
            )
        else:
            parser.add_argument(
                "-" + cfg_key,
                "--" + cfg_list[cfg_key][0],
                default=None,
                help=cfg_list[cfg_key][1],
            )


def parse_args(parser, section_list=[]):
    """ Parses the loaded arguments. """
    for section in section_list:
        __load_args(parser, section)
    return parser.parse_args()


ARGS = parse_args(PARSER, [PARAMETERS])

RESPONSE = HTTP.request('GET', ARGS.url)

SOUP = BeautifulSoup(RESPONSE.data, features="html.parser")

SOUP_SCRIPT = SOUP.find_all("script")

JS_TEXT = SOUP.find('script', type='application/ld+json').text

print(JS_TEXT)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

NOTE: The url I was parsing for the facts is [here](https://www.factslides.com/s-Fact-Of-The-Day).

Answer (score 0):

As long as your json is text/string, you can use `json.loads()` to read that in:

```
import json

JS_TEXT = '''{
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "Article",
"headline": "Fact of the Day: 51 Facts Of the Day for 3/19/2019 ←FACTSlides→",
"image": "https://www.FACTSlides.com/imgs/ishots/8224.png",
"author": "Luke Reiner",
"genre": "facts",
"publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "FACTSlides",
    "logo": {
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "url": "https:\/\/www.factslides.com\/imgs\/logo.png"
    }
},
"url": "https://www.factslides.com/s-Fact-Of-The-Day",
"mainEntityOfPage": "https://www.factslides.com/s-Fact-Of-The-Day",
"datePublished": "2019-03-19",
"dateCreated": "2019-03-19",
"dateModified": "2019-03-19",
"description": "Description.",
"articleBody": "Article clutter here."
}'''


jsonObj = json.loads(JS_TEXT)
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! That helped me open the actual item itself. I will work on this more!

Comment: good job finding that though within the script tags. That's something i learned only about a month or so ago. Completely opened up a whole new level of web-scraping once I learned that.

Comment: @chitown88 - can you please explain your comment?

Comment: sure. Sometimes when you try to parse data from a dynamic page, you won't find the data in the tags until after it's rendered. however, sometimes you can see the data is in a json format within the html source code, within the `<script`> tags. So if you can find_all script tags, and Identify the specific tag that has the json formatted data, you can then pull that text, and read that in `json.loads()`. It's not ALWAYS there, but prior to learning this, I was using Selenium to render the page and then doing a lot of extra work with bs4, when I could have just got the data in a nice json format.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with the help of [@chitown88](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7752296/chitown88).

Here is the functioning code here:

```
""" Get a random fact. """
import argparse
import random
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

PARAMETERS = {
    "u": ["url", "passes in a url.", "1"],
}

PARSER = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="Arguments to parse a url."
)

HTTP = urllib3.PoolManager()


def __load_args(parser, cfg_list):
    """ Loads the passed arguments. """
    for cfg_key in cfg_list:
        if len(cfg_list[cfg_key]) > 3:
            parser.add_argument(
                "-" + cfg_key,
                "--" + cfg_list[cfg_key][0],
                help=cfg_list[cfg_key][1],
                action=cfg_list[cfg_key][2],
                nargs=cfg_list[cfg_key][3],
            )
        else:
            parser.add_argument(
                "-" + cfg_key,
                "--" + cfg_list[cfg_key][0],
                default=None,
                help=cfg_list[cfg_key][1],
            )


def parse_args(parser, section_list=[]):
    """ Parses the loaded arguments. """
    for section in section_list:
        __load_args(parser, section)
    return parser.parse_args()


ARGS = parse_args(PARSER, [PARAMETERS])

RESPONSE = HTTP.request('GET', ARGS.url)

SOUP = BeautifulSoup(RESPONSE.data, features="html.parser")

SOUP_SCRIPT = SOUP.find_all("script")

JS_TEXT = SOUP.find('script', type='application/ld+json').text

JSON_OBJ = json.loads(JS_TEXT)

LIST_TEST = []
# print(JSON_OBJ['articleBody'])
for item in JSON_OBJ['articleBody'].split('. '):
    LIST_TEST.append(item.strip())

print(random.choice(LIST_TEST) + ".")
```

I would like to note that my delimeter is not the best, as some of the 'facts' are spread across two sentences.

Comment: If the solution above helped and was what you were looking for, be sure to accept the answer.